# Xcode 7.3 Simulator Undefined symbols for achitectures

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have a project that runs fine on Simulator when using for example iPhone 6s iOS 9.3 or lower. But when I try to build project on Simulator for example on iPhone 4s iOS 8.1 it does not build.

But weird thing is that I can archive the app, publish it to appstore or fabric and through this two services I can install it on iPhone 4s without any problems. So where is the catch that I am missing out?

In some cases (when I tried changing build settings the app was not able to build or archive at all, but it was able to build and run directly on iPhone 6s only).

I get the following error(s) (Simulator for iPhone 4s iOS 8.1):

```
        Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
      "_Check_Parity_Pitch", referenced from:
          _tdav_codec_g729ab_decode in libtinyDAV.a(tdav_codec_g729.o)
      ...
      ...
      ...
      ld: symbol(s) not found for architecutre i386
      Linker command failed with exit code 1(use -v to see invocation)
```

Project settings:

[image]

I have tried adding and removing Valid Architectures but I got no luck building the app.

Answer (score 1):

Quit your Xcode or simulator and run again. If again it creates problem, then Uninstall Xcode and Install again. Hope it works.

Comment: I tried all of this. Even on other computers but it doesnt help.